# How can I convert it to DateTime without adding a new variable?

Tags: c#, datetime

I'm new in C#.So I have a pretty simple question.
I have a string value.How can I convert it to DateTime without adding a new variable?
Here is the code:

```
string start_date = DateTime.Now.ToString("MM.dd.yyyy");
startdate.Text = start_date;

DateTime start_date = Convert.ToDateTime(start_date); 
start_date = start_date.AddDays(1);
startdate.Text = Convert.ToString(start_date);
```

I would like to convert start_date into start_date without adding variables.
In Convert.ToDateTime(start_date) command I can use startdate.Text instead of start_date....

Comment: Is there any good reason for not wanting to do it the correct way?

Comment: _I would like to convert start_date into start_date_ I am lost.

Comment: @Steve: i'd say that he has already  accomplished his  goal ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Conceptually, you can't.  You can avoid giving the variable a name, but it won't function any differently than if you do decide to give it a name.

Omitting the name, in this case, is as simple as not declaring the identifier, and using the initialized value anywhere that you would have used the identifier:

```
startdate.Text = Convert.ToDateTime(start_date).AddDays(1).ToString();
```

Note that here the variable is still going to exist behind the scenes, it's just not given a name and isn't accessible after the end of the expression.

Answer (score 5):

I guess you are trying to show tomorrow's date. You can do:

```
startdate.Text = DateTime.Now.AddDays(1).ToString();
```

if you want to show date in [specific format](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) than you can do:

```
startdate.Text = DateTime.Now
    .AddDays(1)
    .ToString("MM.dd.yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```